# Display album using PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have a question which is very similar to this one: [Display Album with Photos (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757504/display-album-with-photos-php), however I need a bit of help in applying the code to my situation.

I have two tables, which are related by the column AlbumID:

```
Album: AlbumID, name, date(optional)
Image: ImageID, name, imageURL, AlbumID
```

My PHP code so far:

```
function select_galleryimage($sql,$a_id, $img_id) {
include 'connect.php';
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div id='".$row['AlbumID']."'>\n
    <a  class='$a_id' href=".$row["imageURL"]." target='_blank'>
        <img src=".$row["imageURL"]." alt='".$row['name']."'>
   </a>\n
   </div>\n";
        }
}


  where $sql = SELECT * FROM album JOIN image ON album.AlbumID=image.AlbumID'
  $a_id = 'lightbox' and $img_id = ''
```

The issue that I am having is how to create a loop which creates the divs into which the loop with the images is inserted, so as the end result is something like this:

```
<div id="album1" style="display:none">
                <h1>Gallery</h1>
                    <a class="lightboxX35" href="media/Photos/_MG_7732.jpg"><img src="media/Photos/_MG_7732.jpg"></a>
                    <a class="lightboxX35" href="media/Photos/_MG_7508.jpg"><img src="media/Photos/_MG_7508.jpg"></a>
          </div>
```

## Gallery

Thank you all in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehing like this?

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $current_album = null;

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        if ($current_album <> $row['AlbumID']) {
            if (!empty($current_album))
                echo "</div>\n";
            echo "<div id='".$row['AlbumID']."'>\n";
            echo "<h1>Gallery</h1>\n";
            $current_album := $row['AlbumID'];
        }

        echo "<a  class='$a_id' href='".$row["imageURL"]."' target='_blank'><img src=".$row["imageURL"]." alt='".$row['name']."'></a>\n";            
    }
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```

I haven't tried it on a server so may not be the correct synthax...

With more than a single album you have to sort the `SQL` by album using `ORDER BY` then `echo` the `DIV` fo every new album. To achieve this assign a variable `$current_album = null;` outside the `while` loop then check for changes inside.

Comment: I had already tried that in the past and got this error:    Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPlessons\WebDevelopment\Mosta Dynamic\select_gallery.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPlessons\WebDevelopment\Mosta Dynamic\select_gallery.php on line 8

Comment: this is another story :D

Comment: thanks that fixed it for me :) sorry for getting back so late but was away from computer.

Comment: @ChriMarie You're welcome; we all were stuck with loops in the beginning... keep on `PHP`ing!